# Как реализовать функцию insert на паскаль без использования массива строк и использования доп строки?

Tags: строки, pascal

я набросал такой код, но у меня индекс выходит за границы , сам код

```
function myinsert(substring: string;var s: string; start: integer): string;
var
  i, l,l1, f: integer;
begin
  l := length(substring);
  l1:=length(s);
  l1:=l+l1;
  writeln(l,' ',length(s));
  for i := l1-1 downto start+1 do
  begin
    writeln(i);
  s[i] := s[i - l];
  end;
  f := 1;
  for i := start to start + l - 1 do
  begin
    s[i] := substring[f];
    inc(f);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: SetLength функция вам сильно поможет.

Comment: не поможет, строка по умолчанию имеет длину 256 символов

Comment: А вы все же проверьте...

Comment: мне нужна была функция для турбо паскаля где setlength просто нет, но все же спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я так понимаю Вам нужно, вставить подстроку `substring` в строку `s` начиная с позиции `start`

```pascal
program strIns;

function myinsert(substring: string;var s: string; start: integer): string;
begin
    //проверяем, что позиция `start` не больше чем длина строки в которую нужно вставить
    //хорошо бы еще проверить, что start вообще не отрицательный
    if ( start < length(s) ) then
    begin
      //Отрезаем сначала строки S с первого символа по start
      //затем к ней "приклеиваем" строку substring
      //и доклеиваем остаток строки S
      //по сути мы "раздвинули" строку S в позиции start, и вставили туда substring
      s:=Copy(s,1,start) + substring + Copy(s, start+1, length(s) - length( Copy(s,1,start) ) );
    end else s:= s + substring;
end;


var s, substring: string;
begin
  s := 'Hello world!';
  substring := 'whole ';
  myinsert( substring, s, 6);
  writeln ( s );
  //Получим на выходе "Hello whole world!"
end.
```

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно